# Is there a planned Ethereum protocol change which deals with upgradeable contracts?

Tags: contract-design

There are lots of questions asking how can you deal with contract versions with the current Ethereum protocol. Are there any plans of making protocol-level changes that are aimed to facilitate this process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Planned protocol changes are at:

- https://github.com/ethereum/eips
- https://github.com/ethereum/research

Their corresponding Gitter channels are:

- https://gitter.im/ethereum/eips
- https://gitter.im/ethereum/research

---

Specifically about upgradeable contracts, [DELEGATECALL](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-7.md) has been released.